# Write failed: No space left on device

Tags: php, civicrm.settings.php, admin, webserver, mariadb

We currently have CiviCRM installed in a Bitnami solution in WordPress from a VM in Azure. In the last few days we have experienced problems logging in and when trying to access phpmyadmin we received this message:

> session_write_close(): Write failed: No space left on device (28)
>
> session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please
> verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
> (/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/session)

The answer seems obvious **"The server disk is full"**, however I would not want to rush to change the size of the Virtual Machine in Azure without first trying other options.

By running **df -h** we get the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           796M  524K  796M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        30G   28G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb15      124M   11M  114M   9% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1        16G   24K   15G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
```

We have very important data that increases the MariaDB tables, we have also already **optimized the tables**, but this does not seem to work.

These are the characteristics of the resource created in Azure. (Server)

> **VM:** Standard D2s v3 (2 vcpu, 8 GiB memory) BITNAMI WordPress
> **OS disk:** Storage type - Premium SSD LRS Size | (GiB) - 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root filesystem on `/dev/sdb1` shows as 100% in use which is where your `/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/session` is probably located and makes sense of the error message you are getting.

You either need to expand that `/dev/sdb1` filesystem or move some files from that to another filesystem.  You have 15G free on `/mnt` so you could look at relocating `/opt` or `/opt/bitnami` to `/mnt` - but it depends how big those subtrees are and what level of access you have.

It's just a disk space issue and nothing to do with CiviCRM.